Iteratively Reweighted Least Squares (IRLS) and Gauss-Newton
I am studying nonlinear regression optimization methods. I want to show that the Gauss-Newton method can be seen as an IRLS.  We want to maximize
$$
- \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (y_i - h(\mathbf{x}_i^T \mathbf{\beta}))^2 
$$
Approximating $h(\mathbf{x}_i^T \mathbf{\beta})$ we have
$$
- \sum_{i = 1}^{n} [y_i - h(\mathbf{x}_i^T \mathbf{\beta}^{(t)}) - h'(\mathbf{x}_i^T \mathbf{\beta}) \mathbf{x}_i^T (\mathbf{\beta} - \mathbf{\beta}^{(t)}) ]^2 
$$
and here I don't know what to do. The books I have read do not show what to do when you have any function $h$, or that explain the Gauss-Newton method in a direct way. I would appreciate any kind of help or suggestions. I am also looking for references on the subject in this regard.

Is this generally in the context of GLMs?  Since your function, $h$, is a function of a linear combination, I am inclined to believe so.
